# trigger to copy date to another field

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm writing a trigger so that when I enter a date in Paymentdate__c
field of Invoice object should be reflected in Paymentdate__c of my Accountancy object.

Below is the code I wrote

```
private static void copyDate(List<Invoice__c> invs) {
        Set<Id> inv =  getInvIds(invs);  //getting the invoice id in which the date is entered
        list<Accountancy__c> paymentdate = new list<Accountancy__c>();
            paymentdate = [Select Id,Paymentdate__c, Invoice__c from Accountancy__c where Invoice__c IN :inv AND PaymentDate__c = null];
                for(Accountancy__c pd:paymentdate)
                {
                  pd.PaymentDate__c = inv.get(pd.Invoice__c).Paymentdate__c; //STUCKED OVER HERE
                }
            update paymentdate;   
    }
```

the problem I'm facing is to retrieve the paymentdate from the Invoice object and assign it to the Paymentdate field of Accountancy object.
I was able to do that when I wrote an independent trigger but facing difficulties when writing it in a trigger handler.
how can I access the PaymentDate of the Invoice field?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the `List<Invoice__c` records coming from the call to `copyDate(List<Invoice__c> invs)` contain the `Invoice__c.Paymentdate__c` field already i.e we do not need to query the database within this method?

Comment: yes it have the fields related to Invoice__c so it contains id and Paymentdate__c. The problem is I cannot get the value from the set<Id> using get so what else can be done to retrieve the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the `Invoice__c.Paymentdate__c` coming from the caller, you can use a nested loop to iterate and find related `Accountancy__c` records. Optimising to use Maps may be something you asses on your side, knowing more of the implementation.

```
private static void copyDate(List<Invoice__c> invs) {
    List<Accountancy__c> accountancies = new List<Accountancy__c>();
    for (Accountancy__c accountancy : [Select Id, Paymentdate__c, Invoice__c from Accountancy__c where Invoice__c IN :inv AND PaymentDate__c = null]) {
        for (Invoice__c invoice : invs) {
            if (accountancy.Invoice__c = invoice.Id) {
                accountancy.PaymentDate__c = invoice.Paymentdate__c;
                accountancies.add(accountancy);
            }
        }
    }
    update accountancies;
}
```

Comment: typo: `if (accountancy.Invoice__c = invoice.Id)` should be `if (accountancy.Invoice__c == invoice.Id)`

Comment: its runnnig perfectly. thank you so much @TSmith